# DeleteDuplicates not working for a list in main program

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of dimension $ 50 \times 1 $. The list has some duplicates, I used `DeleteDuplicates` to delete repeated elements, which however seems not working.

But if I copy the same list to some new file and use `DeleteDuplicates`, it is working. I don't know why it is happening like this.

```
s1 = {37.2047, 37.2047, 37.2047, 37.2047, 37.2047, 37.2047, 37.2047, 37.2047, 
      37.2047, 37.2047, 37.2047, 37.2047, 37.2047, 37.2047, 37.2047, 57.3722, 
      126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 
      126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 
      126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 126.14, 131.393, 
      131.393, 131.393, 131.393, 131.393, 131.393, 131.393, 131.393, 131.393, 
      131.393, 131.393, 131.393, 131.393, 131.393, 131.393, 131.393, 131.393, 
      131.393, 131.393, 131.393}

s2 = DeleteDuplicates[s1]
```

It's not working in my main program.

Comment: Then the question can't be answered without the main program. Anyway, if I have to guess: are you using `*Form` function (`NumberForm`, `ScientificForm`, etc.) in your main program?

Comment: The code you provided works fine. So if there is a problem please show us the full code.

Comment: Can you try this. `s2=DeleteDuplicates@Rationalize@s2 // N`

Answer (score 2):

`DeleteDuplicates` is not very tolerant for finite-precision numbers. Maybe that's the issue.

In this example, the last digits are not shown to the user, but `DeleteDuplicates` finds no duplicates.

```
list = {3., 3. + 2 $MachineEpsilon}
```

> `{3., 3.}`

In reality, the numbers are:

> `` {3.`, 3.0000000000000004`} ``

And `DeleteDuplicates` sees this difference:

```
DeleteDuplicates[list]
```

> `{3., 3.}`

Depending on how you copied or imported the numbers, they may be truncated in a similar way. That might be the reason why this "worked" after copying.

Comment: @acoustics - [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) accepts a second argument that is used with pairs of elements to determine whether they should be considered duplicates. The default is equivalent to [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) and requires an exact match. Use `Abs[#1-#2] < tolerance &` where `tolerance` is the difference that you consider significant.